# how can I use "distinct" with all my property

Tags: c#, linq, mvvm

I have a method that allows me to create an agent list.
This list of agents contains "Nom", "Prenom", "Matricule", "Mail".

I use.distinct() to sort them, but this only takes into account "Nom", "Prenom", "Matricule". This does not check if the emails are different. How do I proceed?

The creation of my agent list:

```
private ObservableCollection<AgentMailModel> _Agents;
public ObservableCollection<AgentMailModel> Agents
{
    get
    {
        return _Agents;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value != _Agents)
        {
            _Agents = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Agents");
        }
    }
}

foreach (Destinataire dst in (await _dataService.GetDestinatairesAsync()))
        _TmpAgents.Add(new AgentMailModel() { Matricule = dst.Matricule, Nom = dst.Nom, Prenom = dst.Prenom, Mail = dst.Mail });

foreach (AgentModel ag in (await _dataService.GetAgentsContratsAsync()))
        _TmpAgents.Add(new AgentMailModel() { Matricule = ag.Matricule, Nom = ag.Nom, Prenom = ag.Prenom, Mail = ag.Mail });

Agents = new ObservableCollection<AgentMailModel(_TmpAgents.Distinct());
```

My list in WPF :

[image: list]

My database :

[image: db]

As you can see :
It displays "carré" (cause "Nom" is different, It also works with a different "Prenom" or "Matricule) and only one "carre" (without "é").

Distinct() doesn't work with my Mails. Any tips ?

Comment: [looks like repost for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58605234/observable-collection-distinct-by) [Observable collection "distinct by" - Stack Overflow](http://selvin.pl/repost8.png) ... reposting is bad m'kay?

Comment: Wait, it was supposed to be deleted ! My explanations was a mess

Comment: it' is deleted ... [by reposting I mean delete old question and post the same(or very similar) as new](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265233/what-should-you-do-if-nobody-answers-your-question-can-you-repost-it)

Comment: Oh, ok. So yes, it is, my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two possibilities.

First one is to create a class of `IEqualityComparer` and implement a full comparison.
you can find an example [here](http://dotnetpattern.com/linq-distinct-operator).

The second one is to convert the objects to JSON, and made of comparison of strings instead of objects.

Comment: Thank you. But "Mail" is just a string, there's a reason why he can compare "Nom", or "Matricule", and not "Mail"?

Comment: Who is "he"  ? And if everything is a string, just concatenate the strings as a simple solution.
Why do you say you "sort" things with distinct(), this is not a function for sorting, it's a function to remove doubles.
The IEqualityComparer is the recommended way.

Comment: I just help him with an easy way to create a hash function. I don't talk here about performance